# Executing large Coq project with many files

Tags: makefile, coq

I have a Coq project with a number of files (say x1.v, x2.v, ... xn.v) including a Makefile stored in folder "C:\Users\WK\Desktop\Personal\coq-project" and have installed Coq 8.3 at "C:\Coq" on my Windows 7 machine.

The Coq programs (files) are dependent on each other. How can I execute a single program (say x1.v) in Coq? I want to open a file in Coq and compile line by line to understand it, but it gives errors as there are many imported files in each, with no one in (.vo) format. I think there is some use of commands coqc, coqtop, make or any combination of these but I dont know the exact format of commands, arguments, and order. Please let me give complete commands with full paths keep in mind the above paths.

Thanks,

Wilayat

Answer (score 2):

just run make

It should create all the .vo files, if your Makefile is correct.

Comment: I run C:\Coq\bin\make, it asks for a target, I run C:\Coq\bin\make Makefile, it says "make: *** No rule to make target Makefile. Stop". Do I need to bring Makefile to C:\Coq\bin\ or the whole project or any other suggestion please? Thanks

Comment: If you cd to the directory that contains the Makefile and then type C:\Coq\bin\make, it will find the Makefile automatically.

Comment: I am assuming that your Makefile was produced using coq_makefile.  It should contain a sentence like "# This Makefile was generated by the command line : " and on the next line "# coq_makefile x1.v ..."

Comment: I did that, it created a D file (0 KB) for every file, and with a lot of errors at command prompt. I still can not compile individual files. Yes, it uses coq_makefile V8.3. The project has been created with Coq V8.3. According to the author, Makefile is correct. I think, it should create .vo or .glob file for each. I used command coqc for one independed file, it created a .glob file. Now, other files do not give errors for that file.